# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-2n}$ estimate to 4 decimal places

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I am supposed to estimate the sum correct to 4 decimal places and assume it converges. I know that I am supposed to plug in numbers for $n$ (Instructor says that solving for $n$ is impossible) however I have no clue where to start. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd use a calculator to compute $\sum_{n=1}^Nne^{-2n}$ for some small values of $N$ (say around $N=10$), and see when the error becomes small enough. The sum converges rapidly because of the exponential decay.

Comment: By the way, the sum can be evaluated exactly: it's equal to $\frac{e^{-2}}{(1-e^{-2})^2}$

Comment: there is an exact value for this sum

Comment: You want the last term in your sum to be $ \ N e^{-2N} \ < \ 10^{-4} \ $ , or $ \ \frac{e^{2N}}{N} \ > \ 10,000 \ $ .  You can use the "number fact" that $ \ e^3 \ \approx \ 20 \ $  to give you $ \ e^{12} \ \approx \ 20^4 \ = \ 160,000 \  $ , so $ \ \frac{e^{12}}{6} \ \approx \ 27,000 \ $ .  Backing off by one term will take this ratio down by a factor of about $ \ e^2 \ \approx \ 8 \ $ , which brings the ratio down under 10,000  .  So $ \ N \ = \ 6 \ $ terms should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret you correctly, your instructor is wrong. We can explicitly find the exact answer.
$\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$

Let $S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k n e^{-2n}$ for each $k \in \nn$.

Then given any $k\in\nn$ we have

$\ S_{k+1} - e^{-2} S_k$

$\ = \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} n e^{-2n} - \sum_{n=1}^k n e^{-2(n+1)}$

$\ = \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} n e^{-2n} - \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} (n-1) e^{-2n}$

$\ = \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} e^{-2n}$.

And hence $S_k - e^{-2} S_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} e^{-2n} - (k+1) e^{-2(k+1)}$.

I'll leave you to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} e^{-2n}$ (which is just a geometric series), and then you can find $S_k$, from which you can find $\lim_{k \to \infty} S_k$.

Comment: This analysis is fine, but probably all the instructor meant by "impossible" is that the tail series might be a mixed polynomial/exponential function like $ne^{-2n}$.  Solving for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$ algebraically would require something like the Lambert $W$-function so a student shouldn't expect to be able to do this as an exact formula.  This seems to be a stumbling block for many learners at this stage.

Comment: @ErickWong: Ok if that is what was meant then I interpreted the asker's comment about the instructor's comment wrongly. But no matter, since an exact solution is easy we might as well use it.